# Hash-table based dictionary by implementing movie search

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently trying to write a program that searches through a text file. This text file has a list of movie names and the dates of which they came out. Each line is a new movie. For example:
A tailor Made Man <1931>
A tale of Five Cities <1951>
ect....

I want to make a dictionary that holds key(date) and value(name of movie). I also want to try to make it so I can search through those values and pull a word. For example: if I searched for the word "tale", I will get a list of movie names.

```
def main():
##    print("Hello and welcome to my movie search program.")
##
    searchResult_Txt = input("Please enter text file name you want the search results to go.")
    newTxtFile = open(searchResult_Txt,'w')


    textFile = open('movieData.txt','r')
    textFile.close()
    textFile = open('movieData.txt','r')

   # userSearch = input("Please enter key words or phrases for search.")
    dic = {}
    tempList = []
    for line in textFile.readlines():
        line.lower()
        tempList.append(line)
        newTxtFile.write(str(tempList))

    #return userSearch
    textFile.close()
    newTxtFile.close()

main()
```

This is my code so far. I am still learning python. So, please go easy on me lol. Dictionaries are not my strong point. I wrote the newTxtFile because I wanted to see what was happening. However, it is much faster to put it to a file rather then waiting for python to go through 50,000 lines of movies. Even the smallest of help with be greatly appreciated.

My apologies for not putting the code in correctly. New to the site.

Thank You!

Comment: If your dict has date for its key and a movie title for its value, then you would be storing at most one movie per date. It would make more sense to use movie title for the key and date for the value.

Comment: Like I said before, very bad with dictionaries. Thank you so much. I can use all the help I can get. Thank you.

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code. I would advise brushing up on file handling first. Also, you must do line = line.lower() in order to actually change the value of line.

Comment: alternatively, you may consider using a database, **sqlite** is quite portable for your use case.